# Integration question with trig sub

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

$$\int_{\sqrt{2}}^{2} \frac{1}{t^3 (\sqrt{t^2-1})} dt$$

Well firstly I just tried to solve the integral:

$t=\sec\theta$, then $dt=\sec(\theta)\tan(\theta)d\theta$

$$\int\frac{\sec(\theta)\tan(\theta)}{\sec^3(\theta)\sqrt{\sec^2(\theta)-1}}d\theta$$

$$=\int\frac{1}{\sec^2(\theta)}d\theta$$

$$=\int\frac{1}{2}\big(1+\cos(2\theta)\big)d\theta$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\theta+\frac{1}{4}\sin(2\theta)+C$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\theta+\frac{1}{2}\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)+C$$

$$\implies\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\sec^{-1}(t)+\frac{1}{2}\bigg(\frac{\sqrt{t^2-1}}{t^2}\bigg)\bigg)\bigg|_{\sqrt{2}}^{2}$$

I can't compute $1/\cos(2)$. This is improper, so am I doing this right?

Comment: Yes ..You are correct...$\sec^{-1}(2)=\pi/3$ and $\sec^{-1}(\sqrt2)=\pi/4$

Comment: how do i put this in my calculator, I get "Math Error" o-o

Comment: Well..These are simple to compute...we know that $\sec(\pi/3)=2$ from which we can calculate the inverse function...Same case with other...You need a calculator for more different unknown values..

Comment: Oh nvm i computed wrong that is right